# Vertical scroll iframe not scrolling on iOS

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hope someone can help with this I've tried everything I can think of!

I have an iframe loading within a modal box (click box number 8).

I've used

```
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

on the parent div of the iframe so it scrolls smoothly on iOS but its not working. The background position of body tag is fixed when modal is open to prevent background scrolling. Can anyone help please?!

http://output.jsbin.com/xuqefu